# Java pong game Graphics or geom 2D

Tags: java, awt, pong

My first project is to make the game Pong in Java.
Because I need to calculate the delta for my `x` position and `y` position, I think the best way is to use double variables(excuse me if i'm wrong). But you can't use a double for fill a shape in the lib `java.awt.*`.

Here I calculate the angles after the ball hit a paddle

```
int c = (int) Math.atan2(ball.getPosY(), ball.getPosX());
int delta_x = (int) (1 * Math.cos(c));

    int delta_y = (int) (1 * Math.sin(c));
    this.dx += delta_x;
    this.dy += delta_y;
```

with the `dx` and `dy` I change the position of the `x` and `y` of the pong ball. 
Here I draw my pong ball.

```
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g.fillOval(this.posX, this.posY, 25, 25);
```

If I want the `dx` and `dy` to be more accurate I have to change the type of `delta_y` and `delta_x` to double.
But `fillOval()` is not applicable with double variables. So do I have to make my graphics in `geom.Point2D.Double` instead?

Comment: Please elaborate what your "x position and y position" are, and why you want to use double here.

Comment: Your screen only understands whole numbers.  Double precision was added to allow support for high resolution printing (amongst other things).  While I would encourage the use of the Shape/Graphics2D API, in you situation, I wouldn't be to overly concerned by it either.

Answer (score 2):

Use double values for delta, but have your final coordinates be casted to int.

Like this (in a pseudocode-style thing):

```
int delta_x=1.3, delta_y=-0.4
public void update(){
   double x=(pong_ball.getX()+delta_x);
   double y=(pong_ball.getY()+delta_y);
   pong_ball.setX(x);
   pong_ball.setY(y);
}
// in the pong_ball code
public void paint(Graphics g){
   paintBall((int) x, (int) y);
}
```

EDIT: sorry, I realized a mistake. If the delta is small enough, the ball won't move! Therefore, you need to store the ball's coords in doubles too and only cast when finally painting the ball... Sorry about that

EDIT 2: note that the code above is NOT compilable. you need more code (like the actual x-y fields, the jframe code, etc)

Comment: thanks! i thought the most accurate is to use double, but because the screen only understands whole numbers i guess it doesnt matter to use double so i can use a int instead.

Comment: No, absolutely use a double for calculations, it will make them more precise. Just cast to an int when finally painting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code from Erin W. He uses Graphics 2D:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2007 Eric Woroshow
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
 * obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
 * files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
 * restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,
 * copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
 * Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
 * conditions:
 * 
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
 * included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 * 
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
 * OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
 * NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
 * HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,
 * WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
 * OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */

package ca.ericw.pong;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Pong {

    public static final String GAME_NAME = "PONG!";
    private static final int GAME_WIDTH = 320;
    private static final int GAME_HEIGHT = 240;
    private static final int GAME_FPS = 60;
    private static final int PADDLE_HEIGHT = 60;
    private static final int PADDLE_HALFWIDTH = 5;
    private static final float PADDLE_SPEED = 2f;
    private static final float BALL_RADIUS = 5;
    private static final float BALL_SPEED_INCREASE = 1.05f;
    private static final int GFX_SPACER = 10;
    private static final int SCORE_TO_WIN = 5;
    private static final int INTERPOINT_DELAY = GAME_FPS;
    private static final int INTERGAME_DELAY = 3 * GAME_FPS;

    private Frame window;
    private BufferStrategy bufStrat;
    private boolean[] keys;

    private Font titleFont;
    private Font menuFont;
    private Font scoreFont;
    private Font winnerFont;
    private Stroke centreStroke;

    private boolean finished;

    private int timer;
    private long timeThen, timeNow, timeLate;

    private enum GameState { MENU, INGAME, POINTSCORED, WINNER };
    private GameState state;

    private float playerLY, playerRY;
    private float ballX, ballY, ballVX, ballVY;
    private int playerLScore, playerRScore;
    private boolean singlePlayer;

    /**
     * Creates and runs a new game of Pong.
     */
    public Pong() {
        init();
        run();
        quit();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the game state and display.
     */
    private void init() {
        // setup game state
        titleFont = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 60);
        menuFont = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 10);
        scoreFont = new Font("Fixed Width", Font.BOLD, 80);
        winnerFont = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 18);
        centreStroke = new BasicStroke(BALL_RADIUS, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                                       BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER, 10f, new float[]{8f}, 0f);
        keys = new boolean[256];
        singlePlayer = false;
        state = GameState.MENU;
        resetPoint();

        // setup the game window
        window = new Frame(GAME_NAME);
        window.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        window.setUndecorated(true);
        window.setSize(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt){ finished = true; }
        });
        window.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true; }
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false; }
        });

        // show the window
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.requestFocus();

        // setup double buffering on the display
        window.createBufferStrategy(2);
        bufStrat = window.getBufferStrategy();
    }

    /**
     * Runs the game, executing game logic and rendering the current state.
     */
    private void run() {
        while(!finished) {
            logic();
            render();
            sync();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Cleans up any resources and exits the program as soon as possible.
     */
    private void quit() {
        window.dispose();
    }

    /**
     * Updates the game state for a frame.
     */
    private void logic() {
        if (keys[KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE]) {
            finished = true;
            return;
        }

        switch(state) {
            case MENU:
                updateMenu(); break;
            case INGAME:
                updateGame(); break;
            case POINTSCORED:
                updatePointScored(); break;
            case WINNER:
                updateWinner(); break;
        }
    }

    private void updateMenu() {
        if (keys[KeyEvent.VK_1]) { // start single player game
            singlePlayer = true;
            resetGame();
            state = GameState.INGAME;
        } else if (keys[KeyEvent.VK_2]) { // start two player game
            singlePlayer = false;
            resetGame();
            state = GameState.INGAME;
        }
    }

    private void updateGame() {
        // calculate new position for player one
        if (keys[KeyEvent.VK_A] && playerLY > 20) {
            playerLY -= PADDLE_SPEED;
        }
        if (keys[KeyEvent.VK_Z] && playerLY + PADDLE_HEIGHT < GAME_HEIGHT - 20) {
            playerLY += PADDLE_SPEED;
        }

        // calculate new position for player two 
        if (!singlePlayer) {
            if (keys[KeyEvent.VK_UP] && playerRY > 20) {
                playerRY -= PADDLE_SPEED;
            }
            if (keys[KeyEvent.VK_DOWN] && playerRY + PADDLE_HEIGHT < GAME_HEIGHT - 20) {
                playerRY += PADDLE_SPEED;
            }
        } else {
            updateAI();
        }

        // do collision detection
        updateBallCollision();        

        // calculate new position for the ball
        ballX += ballVX;
        ballY += ballVY;
    }

    private void updatePointScored() {
        timer++;
        if (timer >= INTERPOINT_DELAY) {
            timer = 0;

            if (playerLScore >= SCORE_TO_WIN || playerRScore >= SCORE_TO_WIN) {
                // one player has one after the last point
                state = GameState.WINNER;
            } else {
                // need to keep playing to find a winner
                resetPoint();
                state = GameState.INGAME;
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateWinner() {
        timer++;
        if (timer >= INTERGAME_DELAY) {
            timer = 0;
            state = GameState.MENU;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Renders the current state of the game.
     */
    private void render() {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)bufStrat.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        switch(state) {
            case MENU:
                renderMenu(g); break;
            case INGAME:
            case POINTSCORED:
                renderGame(g); break;
            case WINNER:
                renderWinner(g); break;
        }

        g.dispose();
        bufStrat.show();
    }

    private void renderMenu(Graphics2D g) {
        // clear the screen
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);

        // draw the title
        g.setFont(titleFont);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 70, GAME_WIDTH, 5);
        g.drawString(GAME_NAME, 55, 130);
        g.fillRect(0, 140, GAME_WIDTH, 5);

        // draw the instruction text
        g.setFont(menuFont);
        g.drawString("(1) player - (2) players - (Esc)ape", 70, GAME_HEIGHT - 10);
    }

    private void renderGame(Graphics2D g) {
        // clear the screen
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);

        // draw the scores
        g.setFont(scoreFont);
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(playerLScore), 120, 70);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(playerRScore), 155, 70);

        // draw the top and bottom edges
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(GFX_SPACER, GAME_HEIGHT - 2 * GFX_SPACER, GAME_WIDTH - 2 * GFX_SPACER, GFX_SPACER);
        g.fillRect(GFX_SPACER, GFX_SPACER, GAME_WIDTH - 2 * GFX_SPACER, GFX_SPACER);

        // draw the centre line
        g.setStroke(centreStroke);
        g.drawLine(GAME_WIDTH / 2, 2 * GFX_SPACER, GAME_WIDTH / 2, GAME_HEIGHT - 2 * GFX_SPACER);

        // draw the two paddles
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(GFX_SPACER, (int)playerLY, GFX_SPACER, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
        g.fillRect(GAME_WIDTH - 2 * GFX_SPACER, (int)playerRY, PADDLE_HALFWIDTH * 2, PADDLE_HEIGHT);

        // draw the ball
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect((int)(ballX - BALL_RADIUS), (int)(ballY - BALL_RADIUS),
                   (int)(BALL_RADIUS * 2), (int)(BALL_RADIUS * 2));
    }

    private void renderWinner(Graphics2D g) {
        // render the game in the background
        renderGame(g);
        Color maskBack = new Color(100, 100, 100, 128);
        g.setColor(maskBack);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);

        // draw the winner string
        String winner = (playerLScore > playerRScore)
                            ? "Left player wins!"
                            : "Right player wins!";

        g.setFont(winnerFont);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString(winner, 85, 120);
    }

    /**
     * Resets the position of the ball and paddles for a new point.
     */
    private void resetPoint() {
        playerLY = GAME_HEIGHT / 2 - PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2;
        playerRY = GAME_HEIGHT / 2 - PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2;
        ballX = GAME_WIDTH / 2;
        ballY = GAME_HEIGHT / 2;
        ballVX = (Math.random() > 0.5) ? 2 : -2;
        ballVY = (Math.random() > 0.5) ? 2 : -2;
    }

    /**
     * Resets the game state for a new game.
     */
    private void resetGame() {
        playerLScore = 0;
        playerRScore = 0;
        resetPoint();
    }

    /**
     * Checks for collision of the ball again the walls and player paddles. If a
     * player has scored this method will change the state appropriately.
     */
    private void updateBallCollision() {
        // check for collision against the top and bottom
        if ((ballY - BALL_RADIUS <= 2 * GFX_SPACER) ||
            (ballY + BALL_RADIUS >= GAME_HEIGHT - 2 * GFX_SPACER)) {
            ballVY = -ballVY;
        }

        // check for collision with paddles
        final int PADDLE_HALFHEIGHT = PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2; 

        // calculate the penetration on each axis
        float penRX = PADDLE_HALFWIDTH + BALL_RADIUS - Math.abs(ballX - (GAME_WIDTH - 15));
        float penRY = PADDLE_HALFHEIGHT + BALL_RADIUS - Math.abs(ballY - (playerRY + PADDLE_HALFHEIGHT));
        float penLX = PADDLE_HALFWIDTH + BALL_RADIUS - Math.abs(ballX - 15);
        float penLY = PADDLE_HALFHEIGHT + BALL_RADIUS - Math.abs(ballY - (playerLY + PADDLE_HALFHEIGHT));

        if (penRX > 0 && penRY > 0) { // hit right paddle
            ballVX = -ballVX;
            if (penRX < penRY) {
                ballX -= penRX;
            } else {
                ballY += (ballY > playerRY) ? penRY : -penRY;
                ballVY = -ballVY;
            }
        } else if (penLX > 0 && penLY > 0) { // hit left paddle
            ballVX = -ballVX;
            if (penLX < penLY) {
                ballX += penLX;
            } else {
                ballY += (ballY > playerLY) ? penLY : -penLY;
                ballVY = -ballVY;
            }
        }

        // increase the speed of the ball with every hit
        if ((penRX > 0 && penRY > 0) || (penLX > 0 && penLY > 0)) {
            ballVX *= BALL_SPEED_INCREASE;
            ballVY *= BALL_SPEED_INCREASE;
        }

        // check for points scored
        if (ballX < 0) {
            playerRScore++;
            state = GameState.POINTSCORED;
        } else if (ballX > GAME_WIDTH) {
            playerLScore++;
            state = GameState.POINTSCORED;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs the artificial stupidity calculations for this frame.
     */
    private void updateAI() {
        float paddleDest;

        if (ballVX > 0) {
            // ball is moving toward AI, move paddle to ball
            paddleDest = ballY - PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2;
        } else {
            // ball is moving away, move paddle back to centre
            paddleDest = GAME_HEIGHT / 2 - PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2;
        }

        if (playerRY > paddleDest && playerRY > 20) {
            playerRY -= PADDLE_SPEED;
        } else if (playerRY < paddleDest && playerRY + PADDLE_HEIGHT < GAME_HEIGHT - 20) {
            playerRY += PADDLE_SPEED;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Synchrnoizes the display to the desired frame rate.
     */
    private void sync() {
        long timeOfNextFrame = (1000000000l / GAME_FPS) + timeThen;
        timeNow = System.nanoTime();

        while(timeOfNextFrame > timeNow + timeLate) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            timeNow = System.nanoTime();
        }

        if (timeNow > timeOfNextFrame) {
            timeLate = timeNow - timeOfNextFrame;
        } else {
            timeLate = 0;
        }

        timeThen = timeNow;
    }

    /**
     * Entry point to the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pong p = new Pong();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but he doesn't use 2D for drawing a ball. But i see he cast the x and y of the ball to int. thnx